# Skip first entry in Drupal Views Query?

Tags: drupal, view

I've created a view that selects all nodes of type "shoot". But I want it to select all nodes of type "shoot", EXCEPT for the first entry. So, if the normal result is:

```
Node 1
Node 2
Node 3
```

I want

```
Node 2
Node 3
Node 4
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes - under `Items to display` put `1` in the `offset` field.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, by setting the offset = 1.  The offset specifies the number of items to skip. For example, if this field is 3, the first 3 items will be skipped and not displayed.

For Drupal 6:  Under Items to display put 1 in the offset field.

For Drupal 7:

Under Pager, click the second link.  It probably looks like "Paged, X Items, ...".  From there, you can set the offset.